# F-test: is mutual independence violated for Granger causality?

Tags: time-series, self-study, f-test, granger-causality

I thought that for an F-test to be valid we need mutual independence.

In Granger causality, we use the residual sum of squares derived from two models, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality. However, aren't all residuals within the residual sum of squares (RSS) dependent on each other?

For instance, suppose I fit the model Y(t) = B0 + B1*Y(t-1) + E. I then obtain residuals E using the exact same data the model was trained on, this is what is used to construct RSS. Doesn't this make every residual dependent on every other residual? How is this not a violation of mutual independence? And, if it is a violation of mutual independence, why are we allowed to take an F-test when using Granger causality?